# OpenJDK JMH - What means to use @Params in a measurement?

Tags: jmh

I am new to JMH and I am trying to understand how **@Params** are applyed during a benchmark.  Here is the code I am using:

```
public class BenchmarkMapper
{

    @State (Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class ExecutionPlan
    {

        public Source source;
        public Mapper mapper;

        @Param (
        { "100", "1000", "10000", "100000", "1000000" })
        public int iterations;

        @Setup (Level.Invocation)
        public void setUp()
        {
            this.source = BenchmarkUtils.createSource();
            this.mapper = new Mapper();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Map<Integer, Object> testMap(ExecutionPlan plan)
    {
        Map<Integer, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int index = plan.iterations; index > 0; index--)
        {
            resultMap.put(index, plan.mapper.map(plan.source));
        }

        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

After running it I saw those Parameter iterations being applied:

[image: Parameter Iterations = 100,000]

[image: Parameter Iterations = 1,000,000]

So, what is affected in the Benchmark when I use these **@Params**?  What is the difference in using **@Params** or **@Measurements** annotations?

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [JMH examples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/66fb723292d4/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_27_Params.java), `@Params` annotation enables you to try different configurations through your benchmark. `@Measurement` annotation enables you to set measurement based settings for your benchmark. For example, you can set number of iterations in each fork or you can set time unit of your benchmark with `@Measurement` annotation. Number of calculations for your benchmark is calculated as `forkNumber * measurementIterations * numberOfParams`. I hope it helps!

Comment: I see.  So, in my example, as `numberOfParams` is `iterations` I have `forkNumber * measurementIterations * iterationsFromParams`.  The last one goes for  `100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000`